# Function on all column combinations of n*m matrix yielding a m*m result

Tags: r, function, matrix, combinations

Say I have a function which takes two vectors and returns a single integer, for instance the number of elements in one that is also in the other vector. Like:

```
f <- function(v1,v2)sum(v1 %in% v2)
```

How can I apply that function to all pairwise combinations of m columns in a n*m matrix.

```
set.seed(1)
m <- replicate(3, sample(letters[1:10], size = 5))
dimnames(m) <- list(NULL, paste0('c', 1:ncol(m)))
```

Now,

```
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "c"  "i"  "c" 
[2,] "d"  "j"  "b" 
[3,] "e"  "f"  "f" 
[4,] "g"  "e"  "j" 
[5,] "b"  "a"  "e"
```

And take the function on the first two columns:

```
> f(m[,1], m[,2])
[1] 1 #'e' is shared.
```

How to do that on all column combinations ? The result could be a m*m matrix (where the results are symmetric around the diagonal) or, alternative, it could be a long-format data frame with columns for v1, v2 and the function's result (e.g. the first row would be `c1`, `c2` and `3` )

I tried to investigate the functions `outer` and `expand.grid` but could not find a solution.

Comment: For this specific case, see also `crossprod(table(m, col(m)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sapply(1:3, function(i) sapply(1:3, function(j) f(m[,i], m[,j])))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    5    1    3
#[2,]    1    5    3
#[3,]    3    3    5
```

Or the following output might be friendlier

```
sapply(data.frame(m), function(x1) sapply(data.frame(m), function(x2) f(x1, x2)))
#   c1 c2 c3
#c1  5  1  3
#c2  1  5  3
#c3  3  3  5
```

Answer (score 2):

Using expand.grid to get all combinations, then loop through pairs get length of intersected items.

```
myComb <- expand.grid(colnames(m), colnames(m))

myComb$N <- apply(myComb, 1, function(i){
  length(intersect(m[, i[1]], m[, i[2]]))
  # or use your own function
  # f(m[, i[1]], m[, i[2]])
})

myComb
#   Var1 Var2 N
# 1   c1   c1 5
# 2   c2   c1 1
# 3   c3   c1 3
# 4   c1   c2 1
# 5   c2   c2 5
# 6   c3   c2 3
# 7   c1   c3 3
# 8   c2   c3 3
# 9   c3   c3 5
```

Comment: Nice solution: taking your output of `apply...` you could easily make a matrix `matrix(output, ncol=3)`. Too bad OP didn't specify output format.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `outer`

```
f1 <- function(x, y) length(intersect(m[,x], m[,y]))
res <- outer(colnames(m), colnames(m), FUN = Vectorize(f1))
dimnames(res) <-  list(colnames(m), colnames(m))
res
#   c1 c2 c3
#c1  5  1  3
#c2  1  5  3
#c3  3  3  5
```

Answer (score 0):

A double loop also works. Only thing is I converted `m` to be a dataframe `M`:

```
f <- function(v1,v2)sum(v1 %in% v2)
set.seed(1) #Leads to different m values than you posted
m <- replicate(3, sample(letters[1:10], size = 5))
dimnames(m) <- list(NULL, paste0('c', 1:ncol(m)))

#Convert m to dataframe M
M <- as.data.frame(m)

#Initialize dataframe of answers
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=3, nrow=ncol(M)))

#Loop and get answers
row <- 1
for(i in 1:(ncol(M)-1)){
  for(j in 1:(ncol(M)-i)){
    df[row, 1] <- names(M)[i]
    df[row, 2] <- names(M)[i+j]
    df[row, 3] <- f(M[,i], M[,i+j])
    row <- row+1
  }
}

df
  X1 X2 X3
1 c1 c2  1
2 c1 c3  3
3 c2 c3  3
```